# PIL in Python complains that there are no 'size' attributes to a PixelAccess, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am trying to program an application that will loop through every pixel of a given image, get the rgb value for each, add it to a dictionary (along with amount of occurences) and then give me rundown of the most used rgb values.

However, to be able to loop through images, I need to be able to fetch their size; this proved to be no easy task.

According to the [PIL documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.size), the Image object should have an attribute called 'size'. When I try to run the program, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'PixelAccess' object has no attribute 'size'
```

this is the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import sys

'''
TODO: 
- Get an image
- Loop through all the pixels and get the rgb values
- append rgb values to dict as key, and increment value by 1
- return a "graph" of all the colours and their occurances

TODO LATER:
- couple similar colours together
'''

SIZE = 0

def load_image(path=sys.argv[1]):
    image = Image.open(path)
    im = image.load()
    SIZE = im.size
    return im

keyValue = {}

# set the image object to variable
image = load_image()
print SIZE
```

Which makes no sense at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`image.load` returns a pixel access object that does not have a `size` attribute

```
def load_image(path=sys.argv[1]):
    image = Image.open(path)
    im = image.load()
    SIZE = image.size
    return im
```

is what you want

[documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) for PIL

Answer (score 1):

Note that [PIL (Python Imaging Library)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL) is deprecated and replaced by [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io).

The problem is about the [**PixelAccess**](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/reference/PixelAccess.html) class, not the **Image** class.

Comment: Oh, thanks!

I downloaded Pillow instead, and did the fixes pussinboots suggested. The `image.size` works, but it returns 0, even though I know the picture had dimensions.

Comment: My bad!

I tried to set the SIZE variable within the function. Now that I removed the function, it works! :)